# phpQuery not pulling results from a CSS selector

Tags: php, jquery, css-selectors, phpquery

So I have the following selector:

```
#rso > li > div[class=vsc] > h3 > a.l
```

and it does the job great when I use it in Ruby, but when I try it in php with phpQuery, it doesn't pull anything,

```
foreach(pq('#rso > li > div[class=vsc] > h3 > a.l') as $li) 
    { 
    echo $li;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated as I can't figure out what's going on here.

Comment: That selector will ultimately match `<a>` elements with class `l` (and a whole pedigree of ancestors), not a `<li>`. You might already know this, but the `$li` in your code suggests you might be trying to retrieve `li` elements. Also, instead of `[class=vsc]`, you should be using `div.vsc`

Comment: Yes, try `#rso > li > div.vsc > h3 > a.l`

Comment: The $li is just from some random testing, I am not looking for li, and I did try div.vsc and nothing came up

Answer (score 0):

As  Asad said - thta worked great. Not sure why but it worked.

Comment: div.vsc is not equivalent to div[class="vsc"]. It is equivalent to div[class~="vsc"]. If you want to learn more about css, [read the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).